# Accessing a pod from the outside world

Tags: kubernetes, networking, google-cloud-platform, portforwarding, mailcatcher

i have mailcatcher installed on a GCP pod that i want to access from the outside world.

in my pod config i have this :

```
ports:
- containerPort: 25
      name: smtp
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
```

from the interior of the pod i have

netstat -laputn | grep LIST

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1025          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      142/ruby
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/ruby
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      142/ruby
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/ruby
```

and in the service i have:

```
- name: http
    nodePort: 31080
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: smtp
    nodePort: 31025
    port: 25
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 25
```

but when i do : **telnet externalIP 25** or **telnet externalIP 31025** i got a timeout

Comment: have you tried curl like `curl expternalIP:31025` ?

Comment: does the port 80 work?

Comment: no the 80 don't work and the curl don't work neither

Comment: curl gives a 301 permanent redirect